# Helping Reduce solve an exist statement

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following Reduce problem:

```
Reduce[Exists[{a1, a2, b1, b2},    a1 > 0 && a2 > 0 && b1 > 0 &&     b2 > 0 && -a1 a2 < u <= 1/4 (-4 a1 a2 + x^2) && -b1 b2 < v <= 
    1/4 (-4 b1*b2 + y^2), (-4 a1 a2 - 4 u + x^2) (-4 b1 b2 - 4 v + 
      y^2) == (2 z - (2 a2 b1 + 2 a1 b2 + x y))^2]&& x>0 && y> 0&& z>0, {x, y, z, u, v}, Reals]
```

Mathematica is having a very hard time with this. My first step was to add assumptions that I happen to know are true in this case:

```
Reduce[Exists[{a1, a2, b1, b2}, 
   a1 > 0 && a2 > 0 && b1 > 0 && 
    b2 > 0 && -a1 a2 < u <= 1/4 (-4 a1 a2 + x^2) && -b1 b2 < v <= 
     1/4 (-4 b1*b2 + y^2), (-4 a1 a2 - 4 u + x^2) (-4 b1 b2 - 4 v + 
       y^2) == (2 z - (2 a2 b1 + 2 a1 b2 + x y))^2] && x > 0 && 
  y > 0 && z > 0 && x^2 - 4 u > 0 && y^2 - 4 v > 0 && 
  z > 1/2 (x y - Sqrt[(-4 u + x^2) (-4 v + y^2)]), {x, y, z, u, 
  v}, Reals]
```

These are best assumption that one can hope for here, so I was hoping there is another way to help Reduce (other than adding more assumptions).

One note: Mathematica solves this very very quickly over Positive Reals.

any help would be appriciated.

Thank you

EDIT: Interesting observation, I thought of spliting this into cases.

$u>0,v>0$,

$u>0,v<0$,

$u<0,v>0$

$u<0,v<0$

First one and second one are solved quickly by Mathematica. Third case Mathematica has trouble with for some reason even though by symmetry it is the same as case 2. So the only case left is case 4.